# jQuery filter function regexp

Tags: jquery, regex

Can somebody explain why my elements aren't filtering?

this what wrote in a book, and he sad that if false element will be remove
and will displayed elements with true :

```
$('li').filter(function() { return this.innerHTML.match(/^\d+$/)})
```

I need to filter only li with 14.15 (i want result just li with 14.15)!

http://jsfiddle.net/crew1251/MYXYX/

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>raz</li>
    <li>asdf 14.15</li>
    <li>tri</li>
    <li>chetire_Tri</li>
    <li>pyat</li>


</ul>


$('li').filter(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.match(/^\d+$/);
});
```

Comment: what do you want to filter? Can you write the wanted result with your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find the `li`s that contain digits, you should do the following

```
var listWithDigits = $('li').filter(function () {
    return this.innerHTML.match(/\d+/);
    // return this.innerHTML.match(/\d+$/); // returns lis that end with digits
    // return this.innerHTML.match(/^\d+/); // returns lis that start with digits
    // return this.innerHTML.match(/^\d+$/); // returns lis that contain only digits
});
console.log(listWithDigits.length); // 1
```

Your current regex is failing because it only accepts `li`s that contain only digits, because you've wrapped your regex with `^$`

http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/1/

Comment: doesnt work, i need only 1 result filtered li with digits 14.15

Comment: @user1956570 You must have not looked at http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/1/ , which I posted, you can see that that it correctly logs the one li with 14.15 in it. Maybe you missed the `console.log` See http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/2/

Comment: there must be only li with digits, you have all li

Comment: @user1956570 You are doing something wrong, you can see that the result of the call is a jquery object with a single DOM element in it. I really don't know what part you think is not working. Look closer at the fiddle

Comment: @user1956570 Dang it dude, are you looking at the jsfiddle I gave you? http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/3/  It does not have multiple `li`s in the filtered jQuery object. Show some code to prove your point (like I did) instead of just saying "it doesn't work"

Comment: @user1956570 I'm not sure what it is you don't understand, but what you have shown here is a jQuery object containing only one li. http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/5/ Here, in this other example, I'm hiding only the `li` that contains digits http://jsfiddle.net/MYXYX/6/

Answer (score 1):

You use a wrong pattern, you must remove anchors:

```
$('li').filter(function () {
    return $(this).html().match(/\d/);
});
```

Note that you don't need to test more than one digit, thus the `+` quantifier is useless.

Comment: Why are you calling `$(this).remove()`? OP didn't ask to remove it from the DOM

Comment: yeah without remove, just filtered