# Select the first letter of the last word in a string using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have a list that I would like to filter by last name. I have `a` tags with the alphabet a-z. The goal is when a user clicks a letter then the list gets filtered by last name. So when a user clicks "A" all the list items with last name beginning with "A" shows up.

I believe I have the logic down to show/hide the elements, but I need help with targeting the first letter of the last word in order to implement my logic.

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<ul id="theList">
    <li><a>John Aoe</a></li>
    <li><a>John Boe</a></li>
    <li><a>John Coe</a></li>
    <li><a>John Doe</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could use regex, acoording to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554131/jquery-filter-function-regexp#19554350):

```
reg = new RegExp(letterchosen+'\w+$');
var listwitAlastword = $('li').filter(function () {
     return this.innerHTML.match(reg);
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterarate over "li":

```
$("#theList").find("li").each(function(){
  var a = $(this).find("a").text().split(" ");
  console.log(a[a.length-1].charAt(0))
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k8jjmqL5/

Answer (score 1):

I just used an alert but the code will get the last letter of the last word as long as theres is only two names. 
The `lastindexOf` line will work if they have a middle initial.

```js
var a = "John Aoe".split(" ").pop().charAt(0);
var b = "John Coe".split(" ").pop().charAt(0);
var c ="John Doe".split(" ").pop().charAt(0);
var d ="Max R. Toady"
var e= d.charAt(d.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1)
alert(a +", " + b +", "+ c + ", " + e)
```